# ASP.NET MVC Use javascript value in partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, indexeddb

I have a view with some javascript in it. The javascript has a callback function that is called, when the data i need is ready (from indexeddb).

This data, i want to pass to a partial view - How do i do that? I cannot seem to use ViewData, as that expires as soon as the page renders (thus, before the callback is received). Any ideas? Code is here:

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var somecallback = myFunctionDefinedSomewhere();
        somecallback.onsuccess = function(evt) {
            console.log("Success!");

            var iReallyNeedThisVariable = evt.id;
            @ViewData["iReallyNeedThisVariable"] = iReallyNeedThisVariable;
        }
    </script>

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView", Model.MyCollection.ElementAt(i), new ViewDataDictionary { { "Stuff", true }, { "iReallyNeedThisVariable", @ViewData["iReallyNeedThisVariable"] } });
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView", Model.MyCollection.ElementAt(i), new ViewDataDictionary { { "Stuff", false }, { "iReallyNeedThisVariable", @ViewData["iReallyNeedThisVariable"] } });
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: you are mixing Server side code with JavaScript. You cannot set `ViewBag` from JavaScript. Instead you need to make a `AJAX POST/GET` call to `Controller Action`, then in response either get `PartialView or JSON Data` and use it in your main view.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid any serverside code - im using serviceworkers to make the site work while offline

Comment: unfortunately you cannot do this

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by avoiding Server side code and work while offline. Can you describe your question in detailed? Because even if you want to render partialview dynamically, there should be server hit.

Comment: ServiceWorkers can cache any "normal" http requests, and serve them to the browser when the browser is offline. It does not, AFAIK, support AJAX in the same manner. Besides, this is entirely client-side. I open the client-side indexeddb, and render the page client-side. I just want to delay the rendering of the partial views, till i have an open connection to indexeddb

Comment: I was mistaken. A AJAX call worked very well, and IS supported by serviceworker's "fetch" event. Thank you! If you make an answer, i will accept it @ramiramilu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are mixing Server side code with JavaScript. You cannot set `ViewBag` from JavaScript.

Instead you need to make a `AJAX POST/GET` call to Controller Action (or to the `Service Workers`), then in response either get `PartialView` or `JSON Data` and use it in your main view.

**UPDATE:**
OP confirmed that AJAX call is supported by Service Worker's Fetch event.